# python: order of AND execution

Tags: python, boolean-logic

If I have the following:

```
if a(my_var) and b(my_var):
    do something
```

Can I assume that `b()` is only evaluated if `a()` is `True`? Or might it do `b()` first?

Asking because evaluating `b()` will cause an exception when `a()` is `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the wonderful help of [`help()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help) (hah):

```
>>> help('and')

Boolean operations
******************

   or_test  ::= and_test | or_test "or" and_test
   and_test ::= not_test | and_test "and" not_test
   not_test ::= comparison | "not" not_test

...

The expression ``x and y`` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is false, its
value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value
is returned.

...
```

So yes, if `a(my_var)` returns False, then the function `b` will not be called.

Answer (score 7):

`b()` will only be evaluated if `a(my_var)` is `True`, yes. The `and` operator short-circuits if `a(my_var)` is falsey.

From the [boolean operators documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

You can test this yourself with a function that prints something when called:

```
>>> def noisy(retval):
...     print "Called, returning {!r}".format(retval)
...     return retval
... 
>>> noisy(True) and noisy('whatever')
Called, returning True
Called, returning 'whatever'
'whatever'
>>> noisy(False) and noisy('whatever')
Called, returning False
False
```

Python consideres empty containers and numeric 0 values as false:

```
>>> noisy(0) and noisy('whatever')
Called, returning 0
0
>>> noisy('') and noisy('whatever')
Called, returning ''
''
>>> noisy({}) and noisy('whatever')
Called, returning {}
{}
```

Custom classes can implement a [`__nonzero__` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) to return a boolean flag for the same test, or implement a [`__len__` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) if they are a container type instead; returning `0` means the container is empty and is to be considered false.

On a closely related note, the `or` operator does the same thing, but in reverse. If the first expression evaluates to true the second expression will not be evaluated:

```
>>> noisy('Non-empty string is true') or noisy('whatever')
Called, returning 'Non-empty string is true'
'Non-empty string is true'
>>> noisy('') or noisy('But an empty string is false')
Called, returning ''
Called, returning 'But an empty string is false'
'But an empty string is false'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it is safe to do that. Pythons if conditions are lazily evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler always reads top to down and left to right. So `If False and True` then False is encountered first by the compiler and it exits the if condition. This is valid for all softwares that I know of.